# QRScanner - After scan router navigate dosen't work

Tags: android, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've got problem with cordova-plugin-qrscanner in Angular project. In my component I scan QR code and if scan is completed I want navigate to another component. 
Unfortunately its dosen't work correct. This is part of my code

```
 scan() {

     // QRScanner.prepare();
     const that = this;

      QRScanner.show();
     window.document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('transparentBody');
      QRScanner.scan(displayContents);



     function displayContents(err, text) {
      if(err){
        console.log('error', err);
        // an error occurred, or the scan was canceled (error code `6`)
      } else {
        // The scan completed, display the contents of the QR code:
         alert(text);
this._router.navigate(['/main/depositor']);  // here dosen't work
        if (text) {`enter code here`
          QRScanner.destroy((status) => {
            console.log('destroy scanner', status);
         window.document.querySelector('body').classList.add('transparentBody');
this._router.navigate(['/main/depositor']);  // here too dosen't work
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Somebody have similar problem? On my phone app exit after navigate or do nothing. I have no idea what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. check the console for errors . if any that means

   if(err){

this will true and there is no router navigation what so ever.

2. check the path "/main/depositor" for spelling and if it exists

Comment: 1. No errors in console

2. Path is correct (I create method with this same navigate and it's work)
I think is problem after qrscanner.destroy but I don't know why it dosen't work

Comment: i think QRScanner.show(); needs to add after QRScanner.scan(displayContents);

See the documentation

Comment: Unfortunately  this not help :(